# RestHeart Response without metadata

Tags: javascript, restheart

How can I get a RestHeart response without metadata when I query a collection? (like "_embedded", "_id", "_returned")
Example:

https://restheart.url/test

```
{
  "_embedded": [
    {
      "_id": "5c530d6381e931ba5992ea35",
      "isActive": true,
      "age": 35
    },
    {
      "_id": "5c530d63602cca9789a4ddb0",
      "isActive": true,
      "age": 36
    },
    {
      "_id": "5c530d63275c5a64b643ed4a",
      "isActive": true,
      "age": 37
    },
    {
      "_id": "5c530d63eddff83681b51ebf",
      "isActive": true,
      "age": 27
    },
    {
      "_id": "5c530d63d6ed461d02948520",
      "isActive": true,
      "age": 30
    },
    {
      "_id": "5c530d639ef0e13b0cb6f3d7",
      "isActive": true,
      "age": 24
    }
  ],
  "_id": "test",
  "_returned": 6
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is using the QueryString parameter "np".
Documentation: https://restheart.org/learn/representation-format/

https://restheart.url/test?np

```
[
    {
      "_id": "5c530d6381e931ba5992ea35",
      "isActive": true,
      "age": 35
    },
    {
      "_id": "5c530d63602cca9789a4ddb0",
      "isActive": true,
      "age": 36
    },
    {
      "_id": "5c530d63275c5a64b643ed4a",
      "isActive": true,
      "age": 37
    },
    {
      "_id": "5c530d63eddff83681b51ebf",
      "isActive": true,
      "age": 27
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Te answer above from [Miguel Santos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8671410/miguel-santos) was totally correct. I just want to add that in RESTHeart v4 (released on June 2019) the default [representation format](https://restheart.org/docs/representation-format/) has changed, so it's not HAL anymore and it doesn't use the "embedded" object, unless one configures RESTHeart to do so.

> Following several community feedbacks, RESTHeart Platform v4 introduces a new default representation format that is more compact, easy to use and effective.

**Note**: the previous HAL format is still available, but you need to edit the configuration.

See [upgrade-to-v4](https://restheart.org/docs/v4/upgrade-to-v4/)